# How to solve this error Lineage 14.1 buld for morotola moto c

Tags: android, build

I tried building LOS14.1 from sources using [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763), but I encountered a problem. When the build starts, the following error appears:

```
device/motorola/namath/wpa_supplicant_8_lib/Android.mk:22: build BASIC wpa_supplicant
find: '/home/serveruser/hdd1/archive/motoc_lineage_14.1/out/target/common/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwifi-hal-mock_intermediates': No such file or directory
build/core/base_rules.mk:183: *** vendor/motorola/namath: MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.libstagefright_color_conversion already defined by frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/colorconversion.
build/core/ninja.mk:166: recipe for target '/home/serveruser/hdd1/archive/motoc_lineage_14.1/out/build-lineage_namath.ninja' failed
make: *** [/home/serveruser/hdd1/archive/motoc_lineage_14.1/out/build-lineage_namath.ninja] Error 1
```

I already tried stuff like `export LC_ALL=C`, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong device branch (GitHub). =)